# How can I get a method working with "when" inside a enum class?

Tags: kotlin, enums, case-when

I need this "fun price" method working with the WHEN call. However, I just can't get it done. I need to be able to print out the commented code down below. What am I missing?

```
enum class Tariff {
   STANDARD, EVENT, WEEKEND;

   fun price() {
       when {
           STANDARD -> "1.99"
           EVENT -> "1.49"
           WEEKEND -> "2.99"

       }
   }
}

//val  default = Tariff.STANDARD
//println(default.price()) // gives 1.99
//val weekend  = Tariff.WEEKEND
//println(weekend.price()) // gives 2.99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to the thing (the instance of the enum) on which `price()` is called inside the enum, you use the word `this`, so you should do:

```
fun price() : String {
    return when (this) {
        STANDARD -> "1.99"
        EVENT -> "1.49"
        WEEKEND -> "2.99"
    }
}
```

Note the return type and `return` keyword.

Or:

```
fun price() =
    when (this) {
        STANDARD -> "1.99"
        EVENT -> "1.49"
        WEEKEND -> "2.99"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than enumerating the enum values in a function with `when`, you could consider storing the `price` as a property of the class:

```
enum class Tariff(val price: String) {
    STANDARD("1.99"), EVENT("1.49"), WEEKEND("2.99");
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
fun main() {
    println(Tariff.STANDARD.price)
    println(Tariff.EVENT.price)
    println(Tariff.WEEKEND.price)
}
```

Result:

```
1.99
1.49
2.99
```